# Change color for specific part of cmd window

Tags: colors, cmd

I want to make a cmd, showing a process of something:
This is what the window should look like:

```
-----------
| TESTING |  <-- This text is in green, but background of this part is in black
-----------

Process ... 1% <-- This text is in white
```

And I hope that I can make the line `Process ... 1%` Updating every 0.1 second to `Process ... (%percentage%+1)%`.

I know I can make it like this:

```
@echo off
:loop
echo -----------
echo | TESTING |
echo -----------
echo.
echo Process ... %percentage%^%
echo.
if %percentage%<100% (
timeout /t 0.1 /nobreak >nul
goto loop
) else (
goto end
)

:end
echo -----------
echo | TESTING |
echo -----------
echo.
echo END!
```

**SO**, the problem is :
1. `timeout /t 0.1 /nobreak` will not work, as `timeout /t` must be integer;
2. The color I wanted can't be changed

Can I do this in other programming languages?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a delay.  Adjust the 1000 to adjust the delay to suit you but it will change somewhat on faster or slower machines.

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,1000) do rem
```

Apart from the `color` keyword cmd is rather limited in color but this batch file demonstrates some use of color.

A third party tool can also let you color the screen.

```
@Echo Off
Call :Color A "######" \n E "" C " 21 " E "!" \n B "######" \n
Pause >Nul
Exit /B

:Color
:: v21
:: Arguments: hexColor text [\n] ...
:: \n -> newline ... -> repeat
:: Supported in windows XP, 7, 8.
:: In XP extended ascii characters are printed as dots.
:: For print quotes, use empty text.
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Subst `: "!Temp!" >Nul &`: &Cd \
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
If Not Exist `.7 (
Echo(|(Pause >Nul &Findstr "^" >`)
Set /P "=." >>` <Nul
For /F "delims=;" %%# In (
'"Prompt $H;&For %%_ In (_) Do Rem"') Do (
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.3
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.5
Set /P "=%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#%%#" <Nul >`.7))
:__Color
Set "Text=%~2"
If Not Defined Text (Set Text=^")
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P "LF=" <` &Set "LF=!LF:~0,1!"
For %%# in ("!LF!") Do For %%_ In (
\ / :) Do Set "Text=!Text:%%_=%%~#%%_%%~#!"
For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# in ("!Text!") Do (
If #==#! EndLocal
If \==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . \` Nul
Type `.3) Else If /==%%# (Findstr /A:%~1 . /.\` Nul
Type `.5) Else (Echo %%#\..\`>`.dat
Findstr /F:`.dat /A:%~1 .
Type `.7))
If "\n"=="%~3" (Shift
Echo()
Shift
Shift
If ""=="%~1" Goto :Eof
Goto :__Color
```

Comment: Yes, that's great, although the lines are too long ^.^ But the thing is good. For this line : `for /l %%a in (1,1,1000) do rem` is just repeating rem, cause there's no output, right? However, I want to know that how long will it take to run `rem` or `echo 1 >> a.abc`

Comment: Yes, there is no output with rem, it is just a delay.  You can use a tool called `timethis` written by a `kevin@microsoft.com` to measure how long a command takes.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the coloring part - you can try using [**cmdcolor**](https://github.com/jeremejevs/cmdcolor). In your case, it would be as simple as:

```
echo \033[92m
echo -----------
echo | TESTING |
echo -----------
echo \033[0m
```